# Cmake error - not able to run catkin_make

Tags: catkin-make, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a workspace created and most of my ROS packages are in the workspace. But when I clone a new package and try to run catkin_make I get the following error.

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/jade/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "urdfdom_py" with any of the following names:

urdfdom_pyConfig.cmake
urdfdom_py-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "urdfdom_py" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "urdfdom_py_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "urdfdom_py" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed. 

Call Stack (most recent call first): 
srdfdom/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/.../first_workspace/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".   
See also "/home/.../first_workspace/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log". 
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
$
```

What could be the issue and how can I solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233251/cmake-error---not-able-to-run-catkin_make/) by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2016-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try again after installing `sudo apt-get install ros-jade-urdfdom-py`

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2016-05-02**:
Than you for the correct answer.